# Predicting Fibonacci Using LSTM RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

New to neural nets so please correct my syntax.

I'm trying to create a LSTM RNN that will predict the Fibonacci sequence. When I ran the code below, the loss remains incredibly high (around `35339663592701874176`).

1. Why does the shape of the input have to be `(batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)`? In my example I have `100` data entries so that'd be my `batch_size`, and the Fibonacci sequence takes in `2` inputs so that'd be `input_dim` but what would `timesteps` be in this case? `1`?
2. Shouldn't the the `units` of the LSTM be 1? If I'm understanding correctly, the "units" are just the amount of hidden state nodes that are in the LSTM. So in theory, each of the 2 inputs would have a "1" coefficient weight towards that hidden state after training.
3. Would an RNN be a suitable model for this problem? When I've looked online, most people like to use the Fibonacci sequence as an example to explain how RNN's work.

Thanks for the help!

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers


# Create Training Data
xs = [[[1, 1]]]
ys = []

i = 0
while i < 100:
    ys.append([xs[i][0][0]+xs[i][0][1]])
    xs.append([[xs[i][0][1], ys[len(ys)-1][0]]])
    i = i + 1

del xs[len(xs)-1]

xs = np.array(xs, dtype=float)
ys = np.array(ys, dtype=float)


# Create Model
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.LSTM(1, input_shape=(1, 2)))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mean_absolute_error", metrics=[ 'accuracy' ])

# Train
model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=100000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can't feed a NN data where some of the values are 10^21 times as large as some of the others and expect it to work, it just doesn't happen.
2. You're not doing anything here that actually calls for LSTM (or any RNN), you're not actually using the time dimension, and you're basically just trying to learn addition. Maybe you meant to do something different (like input digits as a sequence, or have the output run for multiple timesteps and give you several values of the sequence), but that's not what you're doing, and it's unclear what you want.
3. The number of units is your memory/procesing capacity. Each unit of an RNN is able to receive values from all of the units in the previous timestep. One unit alone can't do anything interesting, especially with no layer before it to preprocess the data.

Comment: I did mean to for it to learn addition, actually. Just didn't understand why so many tutorials online liked to use Fibonacci sequence as an example for what RNN's do (output goes back into input of hidden layer. their example has nothing to do with time which is exactly what you explained). Thanks!